# Changing fxFlex value in the Component with "setAttribute('fxFlex', '25%')" not Working in Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, frontend, angular-flex-layout

I'm using flexLayout module (see more in https://github.com/angular/flex-layout also in https://alligator.io/angular/flex-layout/) to build responsive div in my Angular application and I want to set the value of fxFlex attribute from my Angular Component.
code in the component.ts:

```
const nav = document.getElementById('nav2'); nav.setAttribute('fxFlex', '5%');
```

code in the html page:

```
<div fxLayout>
<div id="nav2" fxFlex="25%" class="col-md-2.5 bg-white p-1">hello</div>
<div id="nav1">word</div></div>
```

the code should normally should change the size Layout to 5%, but it's not the case, when i inspect the page I found that the attribute has been change but the layout still the same, **oddly when i change it manually in the html code to 5%, i get the result that i wanted.**

I'm using Angular 6, and Typescript 3.1.1

Please, If there is any suggestion, do not hesitate.

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the code should normally should change the size Layout to 5%

No it should not.

Angular directives are ussed in **Typescript**, or in a **pre-build context**.

When you write

```
document.getElementById('nav2'); nav.setAttribute('fxFlex', '5%')
```

You instruct the **Javascript**, that has been **compiled from Typescript** (so in a **post-build context**) to get the element and add an *Angular directive* to your attribute.

The thing is, the code is already compiled, so you can't add typescript to Javascript, otherwise you would have to compile it again (and I'm not even sure you can do that).

I suggest you learn about angular features and how it works before using it. Also, consider posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want someone to offer a solution adapted to your case.

Comment: So, you mean that the Attribute fxFlex will not change if I use document.getElementById in my Component, but i don't understand why the attribute fxFlex did accually changed when i inspected the html element i found 'fxFlex=5%'

Comment: I haven't said that at all. What I have said is that the `fxFlex` you're using is an Angular directive, not an actual HTML attribute.

Comment: I understand now , the question now is how can I change the value of the directive fxFlex in my component do you have any idea ?

Comment: With attirbute binding, `[fxFlex]="condensed ? '5%" : '50%'"`. Consider making another question for this, as you original question is now irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

In angular, you need to use the renderer2 to setAttribute dynamically.

**Example:**

**HTML**

```
<div #myDiv id="nav2" fxFlex="25%" class="col-md-2.5 bg-white p-1"></div>
```

**component.ts**

```
import {ElementRef,Renderer2} from '@angular/core';

...

export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {

    @ViewChild('myDiv') el:ElementRef; // get the refernce of dom element.

    constructor(private rd: Renderer2) {}

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        // Update dom after view initialized.
        this.renderer2.setAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, "fxFlex", "5%");
    }

}
```